# Comparing different asymptotic notations

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

Suppose we have 3 algorithms complexity times at the worst case:

- A = $O(nlogn)$
- B = $O(n\sqrt{n})$
- C = $\Theta(n)$

In my opinion, it is not possible to define the best solution, since we don't know how `C`grows. I'd like to confirm if that's correct.

Comment: How do you define the best? The asymptotic best is clear one. Maybe you have some constraints or size input in mind, where hidden C does matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we *know* how the algorithm `C` running time grows - it's linear, and it's two-side (lower *and* upper) bound.

However there is still not enough information to choose the best (meaning: fastest *in practice*) algorithm here, because:

- We know only upper bounds for algorithms `A` and `B` - they might be more efficient than `C` actually, we just don't know that yet.
- We don't know constants, hidden in the $\Theta$ bounds - they might make the algorithm `C` less practical than `A` or `B` for limited problem size.

Using the given information we can say only that *for some sufficiently large problem size* the algorithm `C` *might* win over algorithms `A` and `B`.